# Create separate drop down list in Excel Cell for each line in the cell

Tags: excel

Need to fill an excel cell using drop down list. The cell should have more than one line(say two for example) separated by ALT-ENTER. Each line should be filled using a drop down list. That is,**two drop down lists in the same cell one below the other**. Any help?

If it is possible then also tell me if it is possible to dynamically insert another drop down if I add another line inside the same cell.

Comment: Inside the same cell? Only with VBA.

Comment: Why same cell though? Typically you'd split this out into two different cells, much easier to setup and maintain, and no VBA required.

Answer (score 0):

Use **3** cells.  Say **A1** and **A2** each has its own drop-down. Then **A3** would contain:

```
=A1 & CHAR(10) & A2
```